# Linq summing by date in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
SiteCode    |     date      |softwarename  |  Success  |      Error
ASZ             2017-08-5         a              1             1
ASZ             2017-08-5         b              2             2
ASZ             2017-08-5         a              3             3
ASZ             2017-08-6         a              6             6
NBL             2017-08-5         a              5             5
```

```
var CurrentCustomer = Database.Session.Query<Customer>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.deleted_at == null 
        && x.Customer_Username == User.Identity.Name);

if(CurrentCustomer != null) 
{
    var CurrentDepValues = Database.Session.Query<deployments>()
        .Where(x => x.SiteCode == CurrentCustomer.SiteCode 
            && x.softwarename == current_type)
        .OrderBy(x => x.date)
        .ToList();
}
```

I have a db like that. I want to get an output like below. The same date values should be sum.

```
SiteCode    |     date      |softwarename  |  Success  |      Error
ASZ             2017-08-5         a              4             4
ASZ             2017-08-6         a              6             6
```

Comment: You can use GroupBy(x=>x.date).Select(blah).ToList()

Comment: But, how will I sum successes and errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `GroupBy`:

```
if(CurrentCustomer != null) {
     var CurrentDepValues = Database.Session.Query<deployments>()
      .Where(x => x.SiteCode == CurrentCustomer.SiteCode 
          && x.softwarename == current_type)
      .GroupBy (x => new {x.SiteCode, x.date, x.softwarename})
      .Select (g => new {
            SiteCode = g.Key.SiteCode,
            Date = g.Key.date,
            SoftwareName = g.Key.softwarename,
            Success = g.Sum(x => x.Success),
            Error = g.Sum(x => x.Error)
      })
      .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
      .ToList();
}
```

**EDIT**

The above will create an anonymous type.
If you would like to get `List<Models.deployments>`, you should do so in the select lambda:

```
.Select (g => new Models.deployments {
            SiteCode = g.Key.SiteCode,
            Date = g.Key.date,
            SoftwareName = g.Key.softwarename,
            Success = g.Sum(x => x.Success),
            Error = g.Sum(x => x.Error)
      })
```

Comment: I have one more question. I can not transfer it to view with the current ViewModel. (public IList<Models.deployments> deployments { get; set; })
How do I write in the ViewModel?